# My <iframe> position changes in safari

Tags: css, iframe

I have an `<iframe>` that displays video content when a menu item is clicked.  The position of the iframe is correct when I open the page in Chrome.  However, the iframe and side menu div shifts out of position when I open the page in Safari and Firefox.  I need to have them open correctly in all browsers for a presentation.  Here is my temp page:

http://www.foxsportsgraphics.com/Lab-presentation/new.html#

Excuse my messy code.  I am fairly new to doing web pages from scratch.

Comment: I don't see differences between the browsers on that page.

Comment: Thank you.. I figured it out.  I just rebuilt the page giving absolute positioning and changing the z-index according to how I want the elements to appear.   I now have an issue with making my webpage expand to full screen mode in a browser.  The container div keeps everything still the same and doesn't expand to fill the screen as it does when I click on the expand icon in the bottom right hand corner of the movie that appears in the iframe.   I need to have the div fill the whole screen the same way that the movie does.  Is that possible?